# $Y$ is equal to the sum of $n$ independent identically distributed Gaussian distribution variables, where $n$ is Poisson distribution

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, poisson-distribution, central-limit-theorem

$Y$ is equal to the sum of $n$ independent identically distributed Gaussian distribution variables, where $n$ is Poisson distribution. If $Y$ is approximated to Gaussian distribution, what is its variance?$$Y = \sum\limits_{i = 0}^n {{x_i}}, $$ where ${x_i} \sim N\left( {0,{\sigma ^2}} \right)$, $n \sim {\rm{Pois}}\left( \lambda  \right)$.

If we directly calculate the variance of $Y$ by summation, the variance is $n{\sigma ^2}$. When $\lambda$ is large, $n{\sigma ^2}$ is a Gaussian distribution variable. That is, $Y$ can be regarded as a Gaussian distribution with ${\sigma ^2_Y}$ as Gaussian r.v. But I can't find any information about this composite distribution.

Comment: Please show us what you have done and where you are stuck, and we will try to guide you to an answer; just asking for a solution is grounds for closing your question!  Having said that, can you calculate the mean and variance of $Y$?

Comment: such a intersting question

Comment: do you guys know how a problem like this ($n$ as r.v) is called?

Comment: I can't find any information about this composite distribution.

Comment: Have you considered applying the Law of Total variance?

Comment: Thanks. This is a compound Poisson distribution. The answer to this question can be obtained by using the law of total variance.

Comment: You are not supposed to know that's $Y$ is even gaussian, please see my question:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/549599/how-to-get-the-variance-of-sum-i-1nx-i-if-n-and-x-i-are-random-varia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute first the distribution of $Y$ conditional on the value of $n$. It is a normal distribution

$$Y_n \sim N(0,n\sigma^2)$$

#### Compound mixture distribution

And the distribution of $Y$ unconditional on $n$ is like a [compound distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_probability_distribution) or [mixture distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution).

$$Y \sim N(0, n\sigma^2) \qquad \text{where $n \sim Pois(\lambda)$}$$ ​

To compute the raw moments you can take the sum of the individual components

$$E(Y) = \sum p(n) E(Y_n) = 0$$
$$E(Y^2) = \sum p(n) E(Y_n^2) = \sum p(n)  n \sigma^2 = \bar{n} \sigma^2 = \lambda \sigma^2$$

And for the variance

$$Var(Y) = E(Y^2) - E(Y)^2 = \lambda \sigma^2$$

#### Product distribution

You can view this also as a product distribution

$$Y = \sqrt{N}X \qquad \text{where $N \sim Pois(\lambda)$ and $X\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$}$$

And then use [this rule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_of_the_product_of_two_random_variables) for the variance of a product of variables

$$Var(XY) = (\sigma_X^2 + \mu_X^2) (\sigma_Y^2 + \mu_Y^2) - \mu_X^2\mu_Y^2$$

We have $\mu_X = 0$ and

$$Var(XY) = \sigma_X^2 (\sigma_Y^2 + \mu_Y^2)$$

note that $(\sigma_Y^2 + \mu_Y^2)$ is equal to the raw moment $E(Y^2)$, and in our case $Y$ is the square root of a Poisson distributed variable so $Y^2$ is distributed as a Poisson distributed variable and it's expectation is $\lambda$.

$$Var(X\sqrt{N}) = \lambda\sigma^2$$

Comment: Thank you for your generous help, the law of total variance can solve this problem well, and the answer is the same as you gave.

Comment: KennTie the law of total variance is analogous to the solution with the viewpoint as the compound mixture distribution.