# In the compound poisson distribution, when do I use that $X_j$ and $N$ are independent?

Tags: probability, compound-distributions

In the context of compound poisson distribution we have:

- $X \sim F$ a random variable;
- $\{X_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a i.i.d. sequence of copies of $X$ - i.e. $X_j \sim F\,\, \forall \, j \in \mathbb{N}$ and $X_i, X_j$ independent for all $i,j \in \mathbb{N}$.
- $N\sim Po(\lambda)$ a Poisson random variable such that $N$ and $X_j$ are **independent** for all $j$.

Define the Poisson Sum as:
$$Y = \sum_{j=1}^N X_{j}$$

Accordingly to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_Poisson_distribution) (Properties section), when we calculate $E(Y)$ or $V(Y)$, I would like to know at what point it is used that $X_j$ and $N$ are independent?

I do not know the importance and use of the independence!
Help!

Comment: It is amusing to contemplate a situation where all these conditions hold *except* the independence of $N$ with each $X_i.$  One of the simplest such is to let $F$ have a Poisson$(\lambda)$ distribution and take $N=X_1.$ Thus, the larger $X_1$ is, the more likely it is you will have a lot of $X_j$ in the sum.  What would this do to $E[Y]$?

Comment: this question is almost answered here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/549599/how-to-get-the-variance-of-sum-i-1nx-i-if-n-and-x-i-are-random-varia

Comment: $$
\begin{align}
\operatorname E(Y) & = \operatorname E(\operatorname E(Y\mid N)) = \operatorname E\left( \operatorname E\left( \sum_{j=1}^N X_j \, \Bigg\vert \, N \right) \right) \\ {} \\
& = \operatorname E\left( \sum_{j=1}^N \operatorname E(X_j\mid N) \,\Bigg\vert\, N \right) = \text{?}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Are you using the linearity of the conditional expectation? I know that $E(X_1 + X_2 |N) = E(X_1|N) + E(X_2|N)$, but $X_1 +  X_2$ is diferent that $X_1+...+X_N$. The former is a deterministic number of sums and the last is a random sums.  Also, I don't know why you still kept the conditionality on N in the general expectation after using linearity? I would put it at the end of the first line: $E(\sum_j^N  E(X_j|N) ) = E(\sum_j^N  E(X_j) ) $ using $E(X_j|N)=E(X_j)$.

Comment: Cross-posted and answered at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4362759/321264