# $E(SN)$ for aggregate claim amount $S$, $S=X_{1}+...+X_{n}, X_{i}$ are iid

Tags: self-study, expected-value, iid

Consider the following model for aggregate claim amounts $S$:

$S=X_{1}+X_{2}+...+X_{N}$

where the $X_{i}$ are independent, identically distributed random variables representing individual claim amounts and N is a random variable, independent of the $X_{i}$
and representing the number of claims. Let $X$ have mean $\mu_{X}$ and let $N$ have mean $\mu_{N}$ and variance $\sigma^2_{N}$. Then $E(SN)$ equals?

I tried to solve it as follows
$E(SN)=E(\sum X_{i}*N)=NE(X_{i})E(N)$. Is this correct given that N is also a random variable?

The answer is $\mu_{X}(\mu^2_{N}+\sigma^2_{N})$

Comment: Note that you can also use math typesetting in Question titles. It would make it easier to read what you're asking about.

Comment: Use the [tower property](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=tower+conditional+expectation) to compute $E[SN] = E[E[SN\mid N]]$ in two simple steps.

Comment: See related question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/549599/).